# Is there a configuration file format that supports colons in the identifiers and multiline values?

Tags: python-3.x, configuration-files

It would be super convenient for my users if my application's configuration file could support identifiers that have colons in the name, and multi-line values. ie...

```
base:sub:sub-sub13 =
    complicated multi * worded string #1
    multi word strin6 @234
```

And then I read it with my Python program like this...

```
config = ConfigObject('new-config')
print(config['base:sub:sub-sub13'])
```

Is there a widely used configuration format that supports this kind of format, and has a Python library already in existence?

Comment: Maybe Clojure-born EDN with string keys will suit you, there are libs for it. Idk what else to use. There might be some radical variants of inifile but from what i see everyone disregards them even if I am right

Comment: Delimited multiline strings are usually easier for users than indentation, unless they are all Pythonistas at least a bit